# "Had I gone to Paris" - Is this right or wrong?

Tags: grammar, verbs, past-tense, questions, structure

"Had I gone-?"
 Is this a correct sentence? If not, what's the right way to express this question?

Is it possibly : Had I been to, instead? 
Or is this arrangement just incorrect?

The question is this setting: A person sees a picture without themselves in it,and asks the person next to them why they're not in the picture.

Comment: Do you mean that they were not in the photo because they were in Paris at the time? If so, 'Had I gone to Paris?' is possible, but something like 'Was that taken while I was in Paris?' would sound more natural.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between "gone to" and "been to" is that the former can refer to the departure only, whereas the latter suggests you went and came back.

For example, you might ask "*where have you gone?*" of someone you cannot see, but "*where have you been?*" of someone that has returned.

So, in the context you have given, where someone is asking themselves if they had been somewhere but perhaps forgotten, "been to" seems a little more fitting because they must have returned, but either works.